# How to assign a graphic to an FMX TImage in the IDE?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, timage

In the Delphi IDE, how do you assign a graphic to a TImage?

In VCL, in the Object Inspector, you use the "Picture" property of the TImage.  But in FMX, I don't see "Picture" in the Object Inspector, or anything else like it ("Bitmap", "Graphic", etc.)

Please have mercy.  I have 20+ years experience in Delphi VCL, but I'm a raw newbie in FireMonkey!

Comment: @KenWhite you should makes this an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The property you're looking for is `MultiResBitmap`. It's use is covered in the documentation under [Using Multi-Resolution Bitmaps](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_Multi-Resolution_Bitmaps). The portion pertaining to `TImage`:

> In TImage controls. **TImage** controls keep a **TFixedMultiResBitmap** multi-resolution bitmap in the **MultiResBitmap** property. **TFixedMultiResBitmap** is the descendant of **TCustomMultiResBitmap**. A **TFixedMultiResBitmap** multi-resolution bitmap can contain any number of bitmap items having different scales. On each device, **TImage** retrieves the most appropriate bitmap to display from the bitmap collection in the **TFixedMultiResBitmap** multi-resolution bitmap and refers to the obtained bitmap with the Bitmap property. The obtained bitmap depends on the device resolution and scales of bitmap items kept in the **TFixedMultiResBitmap** multi-resolution bitmap. If a multi-resolution bitmap does not contain a bitmap item having exactly the scale required by some particular screen, then FireMonkey automatically stretches or zooms out the bitmap item having the most appropriate scale. For information about how this bitmap is obtained, see **Bitmap**. Keep in mind that each bitmap item takes resources of the application's executable on all platforms (even if some bitmap item is never used on a particular platform).